# understading the proof of $\mu(\bigcap_n A_n) = \lim_n \mu(A) $, where $A_n\supset A_{n+1}$

Tags: measure-theory

Question asks Let $A_n$ be a monotone decreasing sequence of measurable sets with $A_n\supset A_{n+1}$, and assume $\mu(A_1)$ is finite. Then, I was asked to show $\mu(\bigcap_n A_n) = \lim_n \mu(A) $. $\mu()$ is a measure.

proof is: Define $B_n = A_1\setminus A_n$, then we have $B_n\subset B_{n+1}$ for all $n$. Then, we have
$$ \mu\left(\bigcup_n B_n\right) = \lim_n \mu(B_n) $$
Also, $\mu(B_n) = \mu(A_1)-\mu(A_n)$ since $A_n \subset A_1$. By countable additivity and $B_n\cap A_n=\emptyset$, we have 
$$\lim_n \mu(B_n) = \mu(A_1) - \lim_n \mu(A_n) $$
Also, 
$$ \lim_n \mu(B_n) =\mu\left(\bigcup_n (A_1\setminus A_n)\right) =  \mu(A_1) - \mu\left(\bigcap_n A_n\right)$$
Then, we obtain $\mu(A_1) - \mu(\bigcap_n A_n) =\mu(A_1) - \lim_n \mu(A_n)  $ and as a result, $\mu(\bigcap_n A_n) =\lim_n \mu(A_n) $

I think this proof is correct, and I do not see any where $\mu(A_1)<\infty$ is needed. Please tell me where I need to use $\mu(A_1)<\infty$ assumption thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using that $\mu(A_1) < \infty$ in the subtraction and cancelation steps, by doing standard arithmetic (as if you are in the real numbers) which is not available on the extended real line.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A_n = (n,\infty),$ the open interval.  Then
$\displaystyle \mu\left( \bigcap_n A_n \right) = \mu(\varnothing) = 0$ but $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_n) = \infty.$

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP apparently understands that the result is not true if $\mu(A_1)=\infty$. He wants to know where he uses the fact that it is not $\infty$ in the proof.